# How do I use vi keybindings at the command line in Radare2?

Tags: radare2

The Radare2 command line (I believe it's called "interactive mode"?) allows bringing back history and editing it with the arrow keys. However, I prefer to use vi/vim keybindings for this. How do I configure this?

I do have a `$HOME/.inputrc` file which contains `set editing-mode vi`, and this works for many programs (presumably all that use GNU Readline or a compatible library).

Alternatively, is there an option available to build Radare2 with Readline?

Comment: try e?? and grep both vi and tailsub like e??-vi  or e??-tailsub

Comment: @blabb I think you mean `e??~vi`, with a tilde instead of a hyphen, right?

Comment: yeah tilde not hyphen blame it on android keyboard

Comment: What what what?  Where's the question: "How do I use vim keybindings in IDA".  Totally jealous rn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `e scr.prompt.vi = true` to enable a limited form of vi key bindings for command line editing. However, this is *very* limited; it's even missing basic movement commands such as <kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>t</kbd>, and some commands such as <kbd>cw</kbd> do not appear to work properly. Searching with vi keybindings is unavailable; you must still use the Emacs <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> syntax to search backwards in your history. And a special warning: <kbd>Enter</kbd> in command mode will do nothing; you must enter insert mode and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter the command you've just brought up or edited.

(I found the setting by searching the configuration variables using `e scr. ~vi`; thanks to @blabb for mentioning this to me.)

Radare2 uses its own command line editing code, in `libr/cons/dietline.c`.